# change factor levels to custom order of a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like below

```
> data = data.frame(name = c('Mike', 'Tony', 'Carol', 'Tim', 'Joe'), veh = c('car', 'bike', 'car', 'car', 'cycle') )
> data
   name   veh
1  Mike   car
2  Tony  bike
3 Carol   car
4   Tim   car
5   Joe cycle
> str(data$name)
 Factor w/ 5 levels "Carol","Joe",..: 3 5 1 4 2
> str(data$veh)
 Factor w/ 3 levels "bike","car","cycle": 2 1 2 2 3
> levels(data$veh)
[1] "bike"  "car"   "cycle"
```

By default the factor levels are set as 1 for bike, 2 for car, 3 for cycle. I need to change factor levels as 1 for car, 2 for cycle and 3 for bike - how do I go about this ?

Comment: `data$veh <- factor(data$veh, levels = c("car", "cycle", "bike"), ordered = TRUE )`. Specify the custom order in the levels argument

Comment: After that check the values `unclass(data$veh)` or `as.integer(data$veh)`

Comment: sorry @satish, didn't notice your comment before posting my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the tidyverse/`forcats` solution, but the base-R solution is to use `factor()` with the `levels` argument specified in the desired order:

```
data$veh <- factor(data$veh, levels=c("car","cycle","bike"))
```

Contrary to common belief, `ordered=TRUE` isn't typically necessary in this case (even ordinary factors have an ordering), *unless* you specifically want to treat the focal variable as an ordinal variable (in which case R will use orthogonal polynomial contrasts, rather than treatment contrasts, by default), or want to be able to use comparison operators on the variable (e.g. `veh > "car"`); if you're not sure, the default (ordinary) factors are probably fine.

Answer (score 5):

We can use `fct_relevel`

```
library(forcats)
data$veh <- fct_relevel(data$veh, c('car', 'cycle', 'bike'))
str(data$veh)
#Factor w/ 3 levels "car","cycle",..: 1 3 1 1 2
```