# change the order of a factor character vector

Tags: r, unordered

I have a character factor-leveled vector.

```
cat <- as.factor(c("AS-GEN-SUM-10-Fall", "AS-GEN-SUM-3-Fall","AS-GEN-SUM-4-Fall","AS-GEN-SUM-5-Fall"))

cat
[1] AS-GEN-SUM-10-Fall AS-GEN-SUM-3-Fall  AS-GEN-SUM-4-Fall  AS-GEN-SUM-5-Fall 
Levels: AS-GEN-SUM-10-Fall AS-GEN-SUM-3-Fall AS-GEN-SUM-4-Fall AS-GEN-SUM-5-Fall
```

As seen, the order starts with the number `-10-` instead of `-3-`. R naturally order them by the first number even though `10` is larger than `3`.

Is there a way to change the order without specifying each name?
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: [change factor levels to custom order of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47962255/change-factor-levels-to-custom-order-of-a-column)

Comment: `factor(vec, levels = stringr::str_sort(unique(vec), numeric = TRUE))`.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento interesting, i thought `gtools::mixedsort(levels(cat))` would work but it seems to interpret hyphens as negatives (or maybe does not work at all) but `str_sort` does work as expected for _this_ example but is there an option to treat hyphens as negative signs?

Comment: @rawr - sorry, to answer your question, not that I'm aware of.  `str_sort()` also seems to only parse the first (block of) digits it encounters, i.e. compare `v <- c("1 2", "1 10"); stringr::str_sort(v); gtools::mixedsort(v)`.  I guess it needs to be used with care.

Comment: @@RitchieSacramento, when I run this code `cat.ordered <- factor(cat, levels = stringr::str_sort(unique(cat), numeric = TRUE))` call the first element, `cat.ordered[1]`, it still give the `10`  `cat.ordered[1]
[1] AS-GEN-SUM-10-Fall`. I see the `Levels` order change though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, find below one possible solution using the `mixedsort()` function from the `gtools` library.

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(gtools)

factor(mixedsort(c("AS-GEN-SUM-10-Fall", "AS-GEN-SUM-3-Fall","AS-GEN-SUM-4-Fall","AS-GEN-SUM-5-Fall"), decreasing = TRUE))
```

- Output

```r
#> [1] AS-GEN-SUM-3-Fall  AS-GEN-SUM-4-Fall  AS-GEN-SUM-5-Fall  AS-GEN-SUM-10-Fall
#> 4 Levels: AS-GEN-SUM-10-Fall AS-GEN-SUM-3-Fall ... AS-GEN-SUM-5-Fall
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>